# System.Net tracing in PowerShell

Tags: debugging, powershell, trace, stack-trace

I am trying to get tracing set up for PowerShell(ISE) and I came across [this link](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/89240-net-network-tracing-powershell.html), but I am running debugView, and nothing seems to be happening. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Basically my goal is to get tracing for `System.Net.WebRequest` working in PowerShell. If there is another way to do it, I'd also be open to that.

Comment: Define "tracing".  Do you want to see extra debug info that .NET emits during a web request?  Or do you want to see all network traffic for a particular web request (ala WireShark or NetMon)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer - which is mine funnily enough - in that link refers to the regular console (powershell.exe) version of powershell. I have to ask some dumb questions:

You created a powershell_ise.exe.config file, not powershell.exe.config, right?

If you're viewing dbgview over remote desktop, you enabled "capture global win32," right?

You have capturing enabled on dbgview, right?

-Oisin

Comment: Yah, I created both powershell and powershell_ise configs. I restarted both powershell ISE and dbgview and it started working. Giving you the correct answer for the help here, and the thread on the other site! :D