# .NET tracing in PowerShell without creating .config file

Tags: .net, powershell, app-config

I know I can enable [.NET tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/tracing-and-instrumenting-applications) by adding [`<system.diagnostics>` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/trace-debug/system-diagnostics-element) to App config (`powershell.exe.config`) in PowerShell installation folder. This is covered in [System.Net tracing in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4879535/850848).

In fact, I too want to log [`System.Net` tracing source (e.g. `FtpWebRequest`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848).

But is there a way to enable tracing locally? Like in the code itself? Or possibly using some command-line switch? Or can I at least have the App config file in a *local* folder, not to have to modify the system-wide settings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just enabling the default trace sources (`Trace.Information` etc.) in code (and therefore in Powershell) is relatively easy.

Doing so for the `System.Net` trace sources is more complicated because they are not publicly accessible.

I have previously seen that in C#, calling a `System.Net` method e.g. `Dns.Resolve` was necessary in order to get the `TraceSource` to be created but this doesn't seem to be needed in Powershell.

So not a great solution... but it depends what your alternatives are I guess:

```
$id = [Environment]::TickCount;
$fileName = "${PSScriptRoot}\Powershell_log_${id}.txt"
$listener1 = [System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener]::New($fileName, "text_listener")
$listener2 = [System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener]::New()
$listener2.Name = "console_listener"

[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::AutoFlush = $true
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Add($listener1) | out-null
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Add($listener2) | out-null

# Use reflection to enable and hook up the TraceSource
$logging = [System.Net.Sockets.Socket].Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Logging")
$flags = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static
$logging.GetField("s_LoggingEnabled", $flags).SetValue($null, $true)
$webTracing = $logging.GetProperty("Web", $flags);
$webTraceSource = [System.Diagnostics.Tracesource]$webTracing.GetValue($null, $null);
$webTraceSource.Switch.Level = [System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels]::Information
$webTracesource.Listeners.Add($listener1) | out-null
$webTracesource.Listeners.Add($listener2)  | out-null

[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::TraceInformation("About to do net stuff");
[System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://www.google.com") | out-null
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::TraceInformation("Finished doing net stuff");

#get rid of the listeners
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Clear();
$webTraceSource.Listeners.Clear();
$listener1.Dispose();
$listener2.Dispose();
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can write tracing in code.

```
Trace.Write("Hello world");
```

If you want something more advanced try [Log4Net](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/) which generates a config file.

Comment: I'm not asking how to trace in my code, I'm asking how to capture/log .NET framework tracing.